# Bash AutoStart script does not copy files from shared folder

Tags: bash, raspbian, autostart

I have added a startup bash script to a device running Raspbian (Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)).

This is my script:

**SysmacApp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /home/pi/App;
mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Service;
mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Service/Data;
mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac;

sudo mount -t cifs //10.10.0.1/SysmacApp /home/pi/App -o username=*****,password=*****
cp /home/pi/App/Service/* /home/pi/Shared/Service -r
cp /home/pi/App/Sysmac/* /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac -r
cp /home/pi/App/Shared/* /home/pi/Shared  
sudo umount /home/pi/App

cd /home/pi/Shared/Service
dotnet ./SysmacService.dll &
sleep 2
cd /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac
dotnet ./SysmacUI.Skia.Gtk.dll &
```

So basically:

- Create some directories if not exists.
- Copy two applications from a shared folder.
- Execute these 2 applications.

The script is executed because the apps run when the device starts, but the information is not copied unless I **manually execute this script in a terminal**.

To run the script I have added an entry to the `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder:

**SysmacApp.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SysmacApp
Comment=Starts sysmac application
Exec=/home/pi/Shared/SysmacApp.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

If I remotely reboot the device the applications are executed but not copied from the shared folder.

What am I doing wrong?

The script works if it is executed from a terminal window.

I'm getting this in the log's file:

```
Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.997131] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.008071] Key type cifs.spnego registered
Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.008110] Key type cifs.idmap registered
Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.010226] CIFS: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3>Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.010253] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\10.10.0.1\SysmacApp
Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.010426] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Sep 15 14:21:07 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.010452] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

Logs show me that eth0 route is added after it tries to mount the volume, so I've added `-o _netdev` to the mount command but with no success.

Comment: I don't know if this is contributing to the problem you're seeing, but I suggest moving the `-r` to before the first file/directory argument.  I.e., `cp -r /home/pi/App/Sysmac/* /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac`.

Comment: That does not solve the problem.

Comment: What do the logs say when the script is executed at startup? Is the same data already in `/home/pi/Shared/Service` and `/home/pi/Shared/Sysmac`? If it is, then the script won't go any further because the `cp` command will prompt for overwrite and not proceed any further until confirmation. To get around this, you can use `cp -f`.

Comment: @NasirRiley If I delete the Sysmac folder, it is created but nothing is copied in it. The script works if it is executed from a terminal session. Let me try with `-f` Seems like is not able to mount the folder at startup. I'm sorry I'm not a Linux user, how can I check startup's logs?

Comment: The logs are in `/var/log/syslog`. You can find this via Google. If you are going to use Linux, then it's in your best interest to learn more about it starting with the basics. What exactly happens when you execute the script via the terminal? Add the details of that to the question. Don't post it in the comments so that it doesn't get lost.

Comment: Are you sure the raspbian network is up prior to the mount?  You don’t test if the mount actually works. Perhaps add a ping loop and exit when 10.10.0.1 ping is successful, then issue the mount

Comment: @rr0ss0rr nope, I've added it to the question, it seems that eth0 routes are mounted later. But I don't know how to solve it other than add `_netdev` to the mount command.

Comment: Are you sure the mount command is succeeding? `sudo` usually requires an interactive environment in order to prompt for credentials

Comment: You missed the looping part. Either loop through the mount until you receive an exit status of 0 or loop through a ping until you receive a successful ping.  Loops should sleep xx seconds before the next try and have a limit so it's not indefinite.

Comment: By now the only solution I found is by adding a `sleep 3` before the mount command.

Comment: The proper way is to use `systemd` with an unit file, with network dependency.

Comment: @GillesQuénot I'm not a Linux user, can you show me some example or point me out to some docs?

Comment: Ask the infamous chat'. Raspian, not a Linux user? So what are you? ^^

Comment: @GillesQuénot Windows mostly, I'm using UNO Platform that allows me to publish a Skia.Gtk project to a Linux machine, so I learnt the basics. (by now)